# Scroll to next div when 50px from top

Tags: jquery

I have several full screen divs dividing up a page setup in the following way:

```
<section class="row full-screen">

</section>

<section class="row full-screen">

</section>

<section class="row full-screen">

</section>
```

When I scroll X amount, lets just say 50px, from the top of the first div I want it to scroll down to the next div, then when the user scrolls 50px again on the second div, scroll to the third div.

It should also work in reverse.

I attempted it below:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $('.full-screen').scrollTop();        
    if (y > 50) {
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop:$('.full-screen').next().top}, 'slow');});
    } else {
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop:$('.full-screen').previous().top}, 'slow');});
    }
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need the `document` scroll value and not `.full_screen`.

So you need to change

`$('.full-screen').scrollTop();`

to

`$(document).scrollTop();`

Answer (score 0):

I've made for one direction as scroll to next element. same as this you can do for reverse also.

```js
var current = $('.full-screen').first();
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(document).scrollTop() - current.offset().top;
  if (y > 50) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: current.next().offset().top
    }, 'slow');
    current = current.next('.full-screen');
  }
});
```

```css
.full-screen {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="row full-screen">

</section>

<section class="row full-screen">

</section>

<section class="row full-screen">

</section>
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to do anything. No error messages either.

Comment: @Rob Try to scroll 50px from top, it will scroll page to second div. Now again scroll 50px for second div. It will scroll to third div. I've not updated for reverse case

Comment: The snippet works but can't get it to work on the actual site. Will keep trying.

Comment: @Rob check if you get any error on console. Also check for debugger while scrolling so you can get whether control goes in to if condition or not.